I don't have the data displayed in the list in the app, written in KivyMD
My code is working and outputs the found data in the console, but not in the application. When entering data into MDTextField, a search is performed in the json file, if the entered data matches the data in "id" or "text", then the entire dictionary containing the entered data is output. Then the selected data is written to the list.
I do not know what to do, I have tried everything, but it does not work.
import os
import time
import subprocess
import schedule

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem, BaseListItem

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

import json

Window.size = (360, 600)
# the problem is somewhere in this piece of code
KV = '''

MDScreen:

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'UUnit'
            type_height: "small"
            theme_font_styles: 'Display'
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 100, 1
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer_left.set_state('open')]]

        Widget:

    MDNavigationLayout:

        MDScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "main_screen"

                MDBoxLayout:
                    md_bg_color: 255, 74, 73, 1
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: '20dp'
                    spacing: '5dp'
                    radius: "10dp"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    size_hint_y: .25
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": .88}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Enter data"
                        text_font_style: "Display"
                        halign: "center"
                        size_hint_x: 1

                    MDTextField:
                        id: search
                        text_font_style: "Display"
                        helper_text: "Example: IS-22"
                        helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                        size_hint_x: 1
                        multiline: False
                        on_text: app.main_screen.search_query = self.text

                    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                        text: "OK"
                        text_font_style: "Display"
                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                        size_hint_x: 1
                        on_release: app.main_screen.search_data()

                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: '20dp'
                    radius: "10dp"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    size_hint_y: .62
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

                    ScrollView:
                        
                        MDList:
                            id: result_list
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height
                    
                    Widget:

My code with functionality
class MainScreen(Screen):
    search_query = StringProperty()
    result_list = ObjectProperty() 

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.result_list = MDList()
        self.data = None

    def load_data(self):
        """Downloading data from a JSON file"""
        try:
            with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                self.data = json.load(f)
            os.system('the_parsing_script.py')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            os.system('parser.py')
            time.sleep(20)
            with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                self.data = json.load(f)

    def search_data(self):
        """Search for data on request"""
        results = []
        for item in self.data:
            if self.search_query.lower() in item['id'].lower() or self.search_query.lower() in item['text'].lower():
                day = item['day']
                data = item['data']
                para = item['para']
                text = item['text']
                results.append({"day": day, "data": data, "para": para, "text": text})
            self.update_results(results)
            
    def update_results(self, results):
        self.result_list.clear_widgets()
        for result in results:
            item_day = OneLineListItem(text=f"{result['day']} - {result['data']}\n{result['para']} : {result['text']}")
            self.result_list.add_widget(item_day)

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        main_screen = MainScreen(name='main_screen')
        sm.add_widget(main_screen)
        main_screen.load_data()
        self.main_screen = main_screen  
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def handle_search(self, query):
        """Processing the search button click"""
        self.main_screen.search_query = query  
        self.main_screen.search_data()


Example().run()

I have tried many things, but all to no avail

Do not pay attention to the error in this part of the code "self.update_results(results)"

Your build() method is returning Builder.load_string(KV), and that return becomes the GUI for your app. Nothing else created in your build() method will be part of your GUI.

I changed it like this and moved everything that was previously in the build method to on_start, but there is no change in the application ---- def build(self): return Builder.load_string(KV) ----- def on_start(self):

Try (in your original code) replacing return Builder.load_string(KV) with sm.add_widget(Builder.load_string(KV)) and then return sm.

An empty application appeared

That's because it is displaying your MainScreen, which has no children.

I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Your MainScreen is an empty Screen, so there is nothing to display.

Thank you, but I solved my question myself, I just initialized the display of the application in the init method of the Example class
